# Error "Cannot Resolve symbol R"

Tags: android-studio-2.1

This problem has been addressed hundreds of times here but I haven't still solved it.

[image]

I have tried everything available on Stack Overflow and everywhere else:

- Build -> Clean Project; Build -> Rebuild Project
- Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle files
- Update SDK Manager (it wasn't updated)
- Add `import android.R` and `import android.R.*`

But now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I had to update to buildToolsVersion "21.1.2".